# Zend_Auth, Zend_Acl and Cron Jobs/Scheduled Tasks

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-acl

I have implemented Zend_Auth & Zend_Acl into a project here at work and its working great. However, previously I had sceduled tasks running at various times of the day which now no longer work correctly due to the login process. These are called via cygwin wget to the URL's. I would like to know if there is a way to disable Auth/Acl for one of my controllers that does all the CRON stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably define a constant in your cron-script and process the authentication code based on that.

For Ex:

cron.php

```
<?php

define("ISCRONJOB", true);

... continue other flow

?>
```

in your auth-controller

```
<?php
# make sure you pass single-quote when checking for a defined constant
if (!defined('ISCRONJOB')) {
    ...
    ... continue authentication process
}
?>
```